# Process a text file to find a value above the PE score threshold of 3.19

Tags: python-2.7, text-files

The text file can be found at [this link](http://interactome-cmp.ucsf.edu/).  What I am interested in is the value of PE score.  Graphically, it appears under the column Feature2 sys.

This is my code:

```
def main():

    file = open ( "combined_scores.txt" , "r" )
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    count_pe=0
    for line in lines:
        line=line.strip()

        line=line[24:31] #1problem is here:the range is not fixed in all line of the file

        if line.find( "3.19") != -1 :  # I need value >=3.19 not only 3.19  
            count_pe = count_pe + 1    
     print ( ">=3.19: ", count_pe )#at the end i need how many times PE>3,19 occur


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you parse the column using tab (\t), and compare with value "3.19". It should be something like below (Python 2.7):

```
with open('combined_scores.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:] # remove the header line
# reset counter
n = 0
for line in lines:
    if float(line.split('\t')[-3]) >= 3.19:
        n = n + 1
# print total count
print 'total=', n
```